# Docker - how to make one container wait loading the other?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

I have a docker-compose.yml file with following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: "my-mysql:latest"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
  backend:
    image: "my-backend:latest"
    ports:
      - 19001:19001
      - 80:80
      - "9001:9000"
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: test
      DB_PASSWORD: test
      DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
      jdbc_url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306

    # command: dockerize -wait tcp://my-mysql:3306 -timeout 120s bin/playBinary
    links:
      - "mysql:mysql"
```

And when running `docker-compose up` - getting this error:

```
mysql_1    | 2018-03-28T16:43:45.595308Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1    | 2018-03-28T16:43:45.597913Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
mysql_1    | 2018-03-28T16:43:45.598094Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
mysql_1    | 2018-03-28T16:43:45.611072Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
mysql_1    | 2018-03-28T16:43:45.611935Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1    | Version: '5.7.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
backend_1  | [info] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'wherehows'
backend_1  | Oops, cannot start the server.
backend_1  | com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
backend_1  |
backend_1  | 1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [test]]
```

How to make first container (MySQL) to be fully (100%) loaded before attempting second (backend) container to start?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0):

the option depends

[depend docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Comment: How can you make sure redis and db are fully loaded before attempting web to start?